# Upgrading to IOS 7.1 status bar issue

Tags: ios7.1

I had my iPhone 5 IOs 7.0 . I optimised my app tp IOS 7 i.e Base SDK 7.0. everything fine. But i just updated to IOS 7.1 and i can see the black status bar. Should I update my Xcode to put the Base SDK to 7.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infact I saw that arm64 architecture was present, all i didi it remove it and back again its working as expected.